# Is it bad practice to return a String literal instead of a Value Object for POST and DELETE methods?

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design, microservices, standards

If you're in a microservice architecture where a business user needs admin capabilities to add and remove items from a database for that service and wants a message saying the operations were successful or not, so not just a 201 response.

When you are returning a response for a POST and DELETE what is the preferred industry practice? To send back a string message saying it was successful or not?  Or would it be better to have a new value object with a member String message, and getter/setter returned, that can be serialized and returned into the response the user will see?

Is there a preferred approach, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The message-body of an HTTP response is, semantically, a *message*.

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

IT WORKED
```

Using plain text for messages is fine when the message recipient is a human, because humans are semantically flexible.  A human familiar with American English is going to understand that message, and if you later decide to change it to a less shouty spelling, the human recipient will probably be able to work it out.

When machines are reading the message, plain text becomes less satisfactory -- the problem comes when you need to change the message, and without structure the machines have a difficult time finding what they need.

If you look at the example above, the headers, including the status-line, conform to a schema designed some 20 years ago.  HTTP clients know how to parse the headers, and identify headers that they care about, and so on, because there is a well specified pattern to how information is encoded into the header of the response.

In the short term, you could define a schema where "IT WORKED" is one of the possible responses, and everybody could write their programs in accordance with that schema.

But when you need to extend the schema, to include more information?  Can you satisfy your future requirements without breaking old clients?

On the other hand, if it is inexpensive to upgrade all of the clients (because they are all under your direct control?) then maybe you don't need an extensible message schema yet.